# How to change boot order back to ubuntu first, when in the ubuntu settings it is set to uefi first?

Tags: boot, deepin-desktop-environment

I have ubuntu dde installed on pc as the only os. In the settings I switched boot from GNU to uefi, now it boots to uefi. Since I can't but into linux I can't switch back to normal boot. I tried to switch boot order in uefi settings to ubuntu first, but it still boots to uefi every time. Any suggestions???